# Can I list all cases when implicit toString() is called for my class?

Tags: java, eclipse, lint, static-code-analysis

For some classes in my project I override **toString()** method. Mainly the purpose is to improve logs readability. This means that such strings are not localized, and should never appear in UI. Also, I am concerned that somewhere the implicit **toString()** will be called instead of using the actual object, e.g. when it is serialized (using some 3rd party library).

Is there a way to list all cases when **toString()** is invoked? Better, have it only for classes in my package, or otherwise filter the trivial cases, like `log("index=" + index)`? Or forbid implicit **toString()** for specific classes in my project?

My project actually uses Java 7 and is compiled for Android. I currently use Eclipse (ADT), and I have Lint analysis enabled. But I am open to switch tools and environments.

Comment: What would be wrong with overriding `toString()` for all the classes you authored and writing out to a log every time it gets invoked?

Comment: I guess you could start with the JDT AST to find infix expressions containing the plus operator. From there you could use the jdt java compiler implementation to detect if an infix expression is a string concatenation. I'm not sure if there are any more kinds of implicit `toString()` calls to look for.

Comment: You could also scan `.class` files and there debug information. An infix expression string concatenation is mapped to string builder calls.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Too many classes, and many corner cases. I don't have good coverage of tests to rely upon (especially when, you know, some situations that depend on the darker corners of Android app lifecycle are not easy to reproduce). That's why we use static analysis.

Comment: Also have a look how code completions work. When I start code completion for the expression `"Foo"+object./*cursor here*/` it suggests `toString()` so it has to know from somewhere that this is not an addition, but a string concatenation.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker: if your object has a `public String qq()` method, then code completion will suggest **.qq()** in your context.

Comment: @AlexCohn But the point I wanted to make is that there must be some API available in JDT that knows that the left side of the infix expression evaluates to a type of `java.lang.String`. So you can be sure that either the right side is also an expression evaluating to `java.lang.String` or an expression whose result is implicitly converted by calling `toString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to Android Studio v. 1.3. It shows the warnings about implicit `toString()` exactly as I wanted!

Answer (score 3):

You can try [JArchitect](http://www.jarchitect.com) and its CQLinq feature, for example you can execute query like this:

> from m in Methods where m.IsUsing ("java.lang.String.toString()")
>   select  m

You can also define advanced queries where you can search for results in a specific packages or classes.

Comment: I still could not find an easy way to have JArchitect work with Android project

Comment: You could analyze the jar file or in case of apk file convert it to jar file.

Comment: I found an easy alternative. Thank you for your input.